# call method action programatically in ADF Mobile

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to call method which is in my binding.  I want to call this method programatically.

I have seen below link. I get error. because it is working fine in ADF.

http://oracleadfhowto.blogspot.in/2012/03/calling-adf-action-binding.html

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code example here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_mobile_update_through_web

MethodExpression me = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getMethodExpression("#{bindings.updateDepartmentsView1.execute}", Object.class, new Class[] {});
        me.invoke(adfELContext, new Object[] {});